# Basic set question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I originally had a post with more then one question which seemed not to work so well so I thought Ill make a separate post. I am wanting to see if someone can look over this for me please.

The question is ,If $A$ , $B$ , $C$ are sets , then $(A \cup B)\setminus (B\setminus C)$  is equal to what?

Then it gave some options, I thought  of it as, it is basically asking the union of A and B with elements Not in B not C. so this seems equivalent to $(A\setminus B) \cup (B \cap C)$

Does that seem correct ?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've got the right answer. To actually prove this, it's easiest just to element chase. For example, if $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (B \cap C)$, then we have two cases:

- If $x \in A \setminus B$, then $x \notin B \setminus C$. But since $x \in A$ and hence $A \cup B$, we get $x \in (A \cup B) \setminus (B \setminus C)$.
- If $x \in B \cap C$, then $x \notin B \setminus C$, and we proceed similarly.

The reverse direction is of similar difficulty.